# How can I subclass Django TextChoices to add additional attributes?

Tags: python, django, django-models, enums, metaclass

I want to use [Django 3.0 TextChoices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#enumeration-types) for a `models.CharField` [choices option](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#choices) and also as an `Enum` in other places in my code.

This is a simplified version of my code:

```py
from django.db import models

class ValueTypeOriginal(models.TextChoices):
    # I know Django will add the label for me, I am just being explicit
    BOOLEAN = 'boolean', 'Boolean'

class Template(models.Model):
    value_type = models.CharField(choices=ValueTypeOriginal.choices)
```

I am wanting to add an additional attribute to the enum members, something so that this call

```
>>> ValueType.BOOLEAN.native_type
bool
```

works.

`bool` here isn't a string, but the [built-in python function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=bool#bool).

[This blog post](http://xion.io/post/code/python-enums-are-ok.html) described doing something like that with `Enum` by overriding `__new__`.

```
class Direction(Enum):
    left = 37, (-1, 0)
    up = 38, (0, -1)
    right = 39, (1, 0)
    down = 40, (0, 1)

    def __new__(cls, keycode, vector):
        obj = object.__new__(cls)
        obj._value_ = keycode
        obj.vector = vector
        return obj
```

Based on that I tried:

```
class ValueTypeModified(models.TextChoices):
     BOOLEAN = ('boolean', bool), 'Boolean'
 
     def __new__(cls, value):
         obj = str.__new__(cls, value)
         obj._value_, obj.native_type = value
         return obj
```

That almost works. I get access to the unique `TextChoices` attributes like `.choices`, and I have the attribute `.native_type` but string comparison doesn't work like it should.

```
>>> ValueTypeOriginal.BOOLEAN == 'boolean'
True
>>> ValueTypeModified.BOOLEAN == 'boolean'
False
```

I think I am misunderstanding the `__new__` method, but I'm stumped as to what I should be doing differently.

**Update**

In response to Ethan Furman's answer I tried

```py
class ValueType(TextChoices):
    BOOLEAN = (('boolean', bool), 'Boolean')
    
    def __new__(cls, value, type):
        obj = str.__new__(value)
        obj._value_ = value
        obj.native_type = type
        return obj
```

but get

```py
TypeError: __new__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'type'
```

So I went back to

```py
class ValueType(TextChoices):
    BOOLEAN = (('boolean', bool), 'Boolean')
    
    def __new__(cls, value):
        obj = str.__new__(value)
        obj._value_ = value[0]
        obj.native_type = value[1]
        return obj
```

but I get:

```py
TypeError: str.__new__(X): X is not a type object (tuple)
```

so then

```py
class ValueType(TextChoices):
    BOOLEAN = (('boolean', bool), 'Boolean')
    
    def __new__(cls, value):
        obj = str.__new__(cls)
        obj._value_ = value[0]
        obj.native_type = value[1]
        return obj
```

gets me back where I started with direct string comparison failing

```
>>> ValueTypeOriginal.BOOLEAN == 'boolean'
True
>>> ValueType.BOOLEAN == 'boolean'
False
```

However,

```
>>> ValueType.BOOLEAN.value == 'boolean'
True
```

So the right value seems to get there, but the enum member itself isn't evaluating like a `ValueType(str, Enum)` but instead like `ValueType(Enum)` on comparisons.

**Update #2**

I've now tried:

```py
class ValueType(TextChoices):
    BOOLEAN = (('boolean', bool), 'Boolean')
    
    def __new__(cls, value):
        obj = str.__new__(cls, value)
        obj._value_ = value[0]
        obj.native_type = value[1]
        return obj
```

```py
class ValueType(str, Choices):
    BOOLEAN = (('boolean', bool), 'Boolean')
    
    def __new__(cls, value):
        obj = str.__new__(cls)
        obj._value_ = value[0]
        obj.native_type = value[1]
        return obj
```

and just to be safe

```py
class ValueType(TextChoices):
    BOOLEAN = (('boolean', bool), 'Boolean')
    
    def __new__(cls, value):
        obj = super().__new__(cls, value)
        obj._value_ = value[0]
        obj.native_type = value[1]
        return obj
```

but none give me direct string comparison as expected.

**Update #3**
I finally understood what Ethan Furman was telling me to do.

*Solution:*

```py
class ValueType(TextChoices):
    BOOLEAN = (('boolean', bool), 'Boolean')
    
    def __new__(cls, value):
        obj = str.__new__(cls, value[0])
        obj._value_ = value[0]
        obj.native_type = value[1]
        return obj
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there.  Part of the difficulty is only the first of the two arguments, i.e. the tuple `('boolean', bool)`, is being passed to the `Enum` machinery.

So, we have two choices:

- keep the tuple as-is and use index-access (your current working solution):

  `def __new__(cls, value):  # value[0] is 'boolean'; value[1] is bool`
- name the arguments in the  `__new__` header:

  `def __new__(cls, svalue, type):  # value is split into named arguments`

Note that I changed the names slightly to hopefully help avoid confusion.

Putting it all together, your final method should look like (using the second option above):

```
def __new__(cls, svalue, type):
    obj = str.__new__(cls, svalue)
    obj._value_ = svalue
    obj.native_type = type
    return obj
```

*Note*:

The first argument to `__new__` is the class of the instance you are trying to create -- typically the same class that the `__new__` method is defined in.  Even though it doesn't look like it, `__new__` is a `classmethod` -- it's just special-cased to not require the `classmethod` decorator.

Comment: I'm trying to map what you suggested onto my code. Since the specific code you gave mixes the example from the blog post (`vector`) and my actual code (`type`) I think I am losing something in translation.

Comment: Specifically I am getting an `TypeError: str.__new__(X): X is not a type object (tuple)`  when passing `obj = str.__new__(value)`

Comment: I've added an update to my question to hopefully explain what I am encountering, if you are willing to take another look. Thank you for helping me on this.

Comment: @kcontr:  Argh, I forgot the `cls` part in `str.__new__(cls, value)`.  Try that.

Comment: I'm still striking out. See Update #2 for my attempts at various combinations.

Comment: I think I finally arrived at what you were telling me. See update #3 Could you perhaps update your answer to reflect the working solution, and could you also explain what the second argument to `str.__new__(cls, value)` is really doing? I'm still fuzzy on that.

Comment: @kcontr:  Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did using some metaclass magick:

```py
class Mwahaha(type(models.TextChoices)):
    def __new__(metacls, classname, bases, classdict):
        native_types = {member: classdict[member][1] for member in classdict._member_names}
        classdict._member_names.clear()
        for member in native_types.keys():
            val = classdict[member][0]
            del classdict[member]
            classdict[member] = val
        cls = super().__new__(metacls, classname, bases, classdict)
        for member, n_t in native_types.items():
            getattr(o, member).native_type = n_t
        return cls
```

and have your class look like

```py
class ValueTypeModified(models.TextChoices, metaclass=Mwahaha):
     BOOLEAN = ('boolean', 'Boolean'), bool
```

The `clear` and `del` are necessary to get around some of the `Enum._dict` protections preventing overriding enums or attributes. However, that's exactly what we want to do here.

There's probably an easier way to do this without resorting to the `metaclass` but I was primed and ready to go that route ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting my own answer so I can explain what I learned thanks to @Ethan Furman's awesome help!

> From your code it looks like `value` is `('boolean', bool)`, so when
> you do
>
> ```
> obj = str.__new__(cls, value)
> ```
>
> `obj` ends up being `"('boolean', bool)"`

That means this will work, even though it wasn't my intention

```py
>>> ValueType.BOOLEAN == str(('boolean', bool))
True
```

Similarly, if I don't pass `value` at all to `str.__new__` constructor (i.e. `str.__new__(cls)`), then `obj` ends up being the empty string `''`, just like calling `str()` with no arguments.

That means this would work, even though it wasn't my intention:

```py
>>> ValueTypeEmptyString.BOOLEAN == ''
True
```

In the end, it really was my misunderstanding of the [`__new__` dunder method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__). Since I am doing a `str.__new__` call not just a generic `object.__new__` call, the first argument should be `str` itself or a subclass of `str`. In my case `TextChoices` is a subclass of str, so `ValueType` is also a subclass of `str` and can be the first argument to the `str.__new__` method.

Then, as the [docs for `__new__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) explain,

> The remaining arguments are those passed to the object constructor expression (the call to the class).

Or in other words, I can think of the remaining arguments as feeding directly into a `str()` call. Since I don't want to stringify the whole tuple, but just the first element of that tuple, I should pass only the first element to the `str.__new__` call.

So putting it all together:

```py
class ValueType(TextChoices):
    BOOLEAN = (('boolean', bool), 'Boolean')
    
    def __new__(cls, value):
        # cls is <enum 'ValueType'>, a subtype of str, while value[0] is `'boolean'`
        obj = str.__new__(cls, value[0])
        # value[0] is again `'boolean'`
        obj._value_ = value[0]
        # value[1] is `bool`
        obj.native_type = value[1]
        return obj
```

The means by which the `ChoicesMeta` metaclass handles the addition of the passed `Boolean` label in the outer tuple, along with the other metaclass magic for `.choices`, isn't totally clear to me, but now I at least have the "working code" I was looking for and

```py
>>> ValueType.BOOLEAN == 'boolean'
True
```

works.